# how to define member of an array as object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I try to define each member of array as object in JavaScript and then use them like a real object there for i write below codes.

```
var arr = [];
for (i=0;i<n;i++){

arr[nemads[i]] = new stocks(nemads[i],urls[i],"");

}
console.log(arr[urls[0]].url +" is : "+arr[urls[0]].myval());
```

but when I call objects I receive following error.

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'arr[urls[0]].url')
```

can I use array's member as new object?

Comment: What is `nemads`? Did you try `arr[nemads[0]].url`?

Comment: `console.log(nemads[0])`. Output?

Comment: arr[i].nemands[i] = new stocks(nemads[i],urls[i],"");   if nemands is some kinda object field   arr = [{}]

Comment: here is a compelete source code http://pastebin.com/Wv0835c5
nemads is an array

Comment: @p.s.w.g nemads is an array yes i try that ..

Comment: Instead of giving us a little preview of what you need and what is nemand. You throw us your long javascript ?

Comment: im try to open a number of urls with phantomjs and they stay open like real web borwser ... when we open tabs ... nemads are name of urls that must be open ...

Answer (score 0):

Use array.push() to add an item to the end of the array.

```
var sample = new Array();
sample.push(new Object());
To do this n times use a for loop.

var n = 100;
var sample = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    sample.push(new Object());
```

Comment: how i call object in this way ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused by your question but something along these lines may be what you are looking for...

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    var obj = 
    {
        nemads : nemads[i],
        url : url[i],
        other: ''
    }

    arrData.push(obj);
}
```

Comment: is the call to nemad.open() an asynchronous call? If so, you probably want to move your callback code inside the "function(status)" portion of  your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way also.

```
arr.push({nemads[0], urls[0], ""});
arr.push({nemads[1], urls[1], ""});
```